# how to say that the food is done but not fired

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, food

my context is:

i am cooking eggs and they are about to be done.
by done i mean they are eatable and not fired.
by fired i mean they are not eatable.

i know it is hard to understand because i am searching for the correct word.

so please how do i say that the food is done good and not fired. so it is nicely red and eatable.

i searched and they only word i found is "cooked" but that is not what i need. cooked means transferred from row material to something that is digestible.

Comment: They are now: cooked, ready, ready to eat. Soon they will be over-cooked, over-done, burnt, spoiled, I think that may be what you are looking for but it is not quite clear to me.

Comment: We don't say 'fired', we say burned (or burnt in British English).

Comment: Cooked can mean completely ready to eat after having been transformed from raw material. Food can by uncooked, partly cooked, nearly cooked, and completely cooked. The last state can be called 'cooked'.

Comment: [**Many corrections for you to make**: Please use caps for I. raw, with an a. You mean the **food is cooked and not burned**.// Sorry, nicely red?? We say that meat, not eggs, is nicely **browned**, and eggs are nicely fried. Not fired. Finally, transformed, not transferred.]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i am cooking eggs and they are about to be

"done" or "ready"

> by done I mean they are eatable and not:

"burnt" or "overcooked"